# How to write SQL query to return correct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm not able to solve this problem to retrieve only the records with 'Approved' Status where the ChangedDate is max value - that is the latest status of the forms are 'Approved' only

The two tables are **Forms** and **FormStatuses**, with FormStatuses holding multiple status records of a form record as below in a 1 to many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Forms]
(
[FormId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Property1] [bit]  NULL,
[Property2] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Forms_FormId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[FormId] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormStatuses]
(
[FormStatusId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FormId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ChangedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_FormStatuses_FormStatusId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[FormStatusId] ASC
)
```

Sample of data for FormStatuses - should return only FormId=5276:

```
FormId    Status     ChangedDate
5277      PENDING    1/2/2009 12.10.11.022
5277      RETURNED   2/2/2010 10.20.11.022
5277      APPROVED   5/2/2010 10.20.11.022
5277      RETURNED   5/5/2010 10.20.11.022
5277      APPROVED   1/1/2011 13:48.52.043
5277      REJECTED   1/1/2011 13.52.50.011
5276      DRAFT      4/3/2011 15.10.11.022
5276      APPROVED   3/3/2012 14.10.11.022
5275      DRAFT      3/1/2010 13.10.11.022
5275      PENDING    2/2/2011 12.10.11.022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Forms.FormID,   
    Forms.Property1,
    Forms.Property2,
    fs1.Status,
    fs1.ChangedDate
FROM
    forms,
    FormStatuses fs1
JOIN
    (SELECT
        MAX(fs2.ChangedDate) AS latest,
        fs2.FormID
    FROM
        FormStatuses fs2
    GROUP BY
        fs2.FormID) as maxstatus
ON
    fs1.ChangedDate = latest AND
    fs1.FormID = maxstatus.FormID
WHERE
    fs1.FormID = Forms.FormID AND
    fs1.Status = "Approved"
```

This creates a Join table that has the form ID and max status date to use to compare and determine if the status at that max status date is "Approved".

Comment: Right CharlieGirl, thanks, appreciate much the quick solution you provided!

Comment: Was there an issue with the testing?  This is no longer marked as the correct answer.  How can I improve it?

Comment: CharlieGirl, your solution also works and it's much appreciated. I had marked as correct, so I am also wondering how it got unmarked. But thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT
      FormId
    , MAX(FormStatusId) AS 'FormStatusId'
 FROM FormStatuses
GROUP BY FormId
)

SELECT 
       F.FormId
     , F.Property1
     , F.Property2
     , FS.Status
     , FS.ChangedDate
  FROM Forms F JOIN T T ON F.FormId = T.FormId
               JOIN FormStatuses FS ON T.FormStatusId = FS.FormStatusId
                                   AND FS.Status = 'Approved'
```

Comment: @Ashish please test this query

Comment: I need to return only records with Approved status as the latest status, otherwise ignore the form record

Comment: @AshishYengkhom please test my changes

Comment: @AshishYengkhom I implemented your requirements, please test

Comment: Thanks Hasan, this CTE did it correctly. Appreciate it much.

Comment: My apologies Hasan, but this didn't actually return the correct results. I was testing and I had an incorrect record included that had some other status other than APPROVED as the latest changed date. The FormStatus table allows multiple Approved or any other status values. That is from a business rule, the same Form can be Approved, Rejected and then Approved again.

Comment: Thanks, I added timestamps and a couple more sample records for a better understanding of the problem

Comment: This works too Hasan and nicely done! The Max(FormStatusId) makes it so much simpler - why didn't I think about it earlier :-)

Comment: @AshishYengkhom yes, the point of my answer: "Simplicity is the power"